# For loop not working inside set state of button press

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code

```
TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              for (int i = 0; i == seasonList.length; i++) {
                seasonList[i].color = 0xff808080; //grey
              }
              seasonList[index].color = 0xff000000; //black
            });
          },
```

Pretty much, what this code is supposed to do is that when I press on the `TextButton` every other button should become grey again and only the pressed one black. However, what ends up happening is that my code acts totally as if that for loop did not exist at all, making every button black as I press them, but leaving them black when I press another one.

Please let me know what is wrong.

Full code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(TradingPage());

Season venus = Season('Venus');
Season helado = Season('Helado');
Season year1800s = Season('1800s');
Season neonArt = Season('Neon Art');
Season ritmo = Season('Ritmo');
Season lente = Season('Lente');
Season joyasPreciosas = Season('Joyas');

List<Season> seasonList = [
  venus,
  helado,
  year1800s,
  neonArt,
  ritmo,
  lente,
  joyasPreciosas,
];

class TradingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          title: Text(
            'Relatable',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 3,
                    blurRadius: 6,
                    offset: Offset(0, 1),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 30.0,
              child: chooseSeasonBar(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class chooseSeasonBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _chooseSeasonBarState createState() => _chooseSeasonBarState();
}

class _chooseSeasonBarState extends State<chooseSeasonBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            for (int i = 0; i == seasonList.length; i++) {
              setState(() {
                seasonList[i].color = 0xff808080; //grey
              });
            }
            setState(() {
              seasonList[index].color = 0xff000000; //black
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            child: Text(
              seasonList[index].name,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(seasonList[index].color)), //grey
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: seasonList.length,
    );
  }
}

class Season {
  String name;
  int color = 0xff808080; //grey

  Season(this.name);
}
```

Comment: Do you can to try to put the setState inside the for?

Comment: @Y.Sampaio didn't work :(

Comment: Your loop condition is backwards, so your loop will never iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
            seasonList.forEach((element) {
              setState(() {
                element.color = 0xff808080;
              });
            });
            setState(() {
              seasonList[index].color = 0xff000000;
            });
```

Comment: See my comment on the question for *why* the original code didn't work.  Also you generally should prefer `for-in` loops over using `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with a single setState call...

for (int i = 0; **i < seasonList.length**; i++)

```
onPressed: () {
   for (int i = 0; i < seasonList.length; i++) {
       seasonList[i].color = 0xff808080;
   }
   seasonList[index].color = 0xffff0000;
   setState(() => {});
}
```